# How could I animate something being pulled almost endlessly without changing shape

Tags: modeling, animation, armature

So my idea is that I have a bracelet type object that'll be pulled between a still object and a moving one, but I want it to uncoil for about a second before stopping and being pulled back. Sorta like Spawns chains, how they move almost snake-like throughout the air and return to him.

Comment: hello, maybe show a story board with the different steps, like 3 images?